# Rails: complex search on 3 models, return only newest - how to do this?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to add an advanced search option to my app in which the user can search for certain links based on attributes from 3 different models.

My app is set up so that a `User has_many :websites`, `Website has_many :links`, and `Link has_many :stats`

I know how create SQL queries with joins or includes etc in Rails **but** I'm getting stuck since I only want to retrieve the latest stat for each link and not all of them - and I don't know the most efficient way to do this.

So for example, let's say a user has 2 websites, each with 10 links, and each link has 100 stats, that's 2,022 objects total, but I only want to search through 42 objects (only 1 stat per link).

Once I get only those 42 objects in a database query I can add `.where("attribute like ?", user_input)` and return the correct links.

### Update

I've tried adding the following to my Link model:

```
has_many :stats, dependent: :destroy
has_many :one_stat, class_name: "Stat", order: "id ASC", limit: 1
```

But this doesn't seem to work, for example if I do:

```
@links = Link.includes(:one_stat).all

@links.each do |l|
  puts l.one_stat.size
end
```

Instead of getting `1, 1, 1...` I get the number of all the stats: `125, 40, 76...`.

Can I use the limit option to get the results I want or does it not work that way?

### 2nd Update

I've updated my code according to Erez's advice, but still not working properly:

```
has_one :latest_stat, class_name: "Stat", order: "id ASC"

@links = Link.includes(:latest_stat)

@links.each do |l|
  puts l.latest_stat.indexed
end

=> true
=> true
=> true
=> false
=> true
=> true
=> true

Link.includes(:latest_stat).where("stats.indexed = ?", false).count
=> 6

Link.includes(:latest_stat).where("stats.indexed = ?", true).count
=> 7
```

It should return 1 and 6, but it's still checking all the stats rather than the latest only.

Comment: Something like `current_user.stats.includes(:link, link: :website).where(...)` - but then I don't know how to limit the stats to 1 per link. Only thing I could think of is looping through the results or multiple database queries, but these both sound like bad ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, you gotta break through the AR abstraction and get your SQL on. Just a tiny bit.

Let's assume you have really simple relationships: `Website` `has_many :links`, and `Link` `belongs_to :website` and `has_many :stats`, and `Stat` `belongs_to :link`. No denormalization anywhere. Now, you want to build a query that finds, all of their links, and, for each link, the latest stat, but only for stats with some property (or it could be websites with some property or links with some property).

Untested, but something like:

```
Website
  .includes(:links => :stats)
  .where("stats.indexed" => true)
  .where("stats.id = (select max(stats2.id) 
     from stats stats2 where stats2.link_id = links.id)")
```

That last bit subselects stats that are part of each link and finds the max id. It then filters out stats (from the join at the top) that don't match that max id. The query returns websites, which each have some number of links, and each link has just one stat in its `stats` collection.

**Some extra info**

I originally wrote this answer in terms of [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), which turned out to be overkill, but I think I should cover it here anyway, since, well, fun. You'll note that the aggregate function trick we used above only works because we're determining which stat to use based on its ID, which exactly the property we need to filter the stats from the join by. But let's say you wanted only the first stat as ranked by some criteria other than ID, such as as, say, `number_of_clicks`; that trick won't work anymore because the aggregation loses track of the IDs. That's where window functions come in.

Again, totally untested:

```
Website
  .includes(:links => :stats)
  .where("stats.indexed" => true)
  .where(                                 
     "(stats.id, 1) in (
       select id, row_number() 
       over (partition by stats2.id order by stats2.number_of_clicks DESC)
       from stat stats2 where stats2.link_id = links.id
     )"
   )
```

That last `where` subselects stats that match each link and order them by `number_of_clicks` ascending, then the `in` part matches it to a stat from the join. Note that window queries aren't portable to other database platforms. You could also use this technique to solve the original problem you posed (just swap `stats2.id` for `stats2.number_of_clicks`); it could conceivably perform better, and is advocated by this [blog post](http://blog.hashrocket.com/posts/sql-window-functions).

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for! It worked after I changed `max(stats2.link_id)` to `max(stats2.id)`. The final code I'm using is something like `current_user.rentals.includes(:website, :stats).where("stats.id = (select max(stats2.id) from stats stats2 where stats2.rental_id = rentals.id)").where(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
has_one :latest_stat, class_name: "Stat", order: "id ASC"

@links = Link.includes(:latest_stat)

@links.each do |l|
  puts l.latest_stat
end
```

Note you can't print `latest_stat.size` since it is the stat object itself and not a relation.

Comment: this is cleaner than what I had, but please have a look at my updated answer, it's still not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@user.websites.map { |site| site.links.map { |link| link.stats.last } }.flatten
```

For a given user, this will return an array with that contains the last stats for the links on that users website.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear in my question. I'm trying to search through those objects and return only the sites that a user is looking for. I'll update my question to be more specific.